# My algorithm for replacing characters in string is not working

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, cs50, c-strings

For example when I input in the terminal

> hello there

it prints

> gmllg mgmkm

instead of printing

> itssg zitkt

which is not supposed to happen.

Another example is when I input in the terminal

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

it prints

> jvmkmnbgghaldfghjklmbcvbnm

the last 5 characters are right
but its supposed to print

> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm

Anyways I can fix this?

Here is the code below

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void replace_char(string text, string replace, string new);
int main(void){

    string message = get_string("Type message: ");
    string Alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string Key  =  "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    replace_char(message, Alpha, Key);
    printf("%s\n", message);
}
void replace_char(string text, string replace, string new){

    int strl = strlen(text);
    int h;
    int p;
    for (h = 0; h < strl; h++){
        for (p = 0; p < 26; p++)
        if (text[h] == replace[p])
        text[h] = new[p];}
}
```

Comment: You don't need `replace`, you don't need the inner `for` loop, and you don't need the `if` statement. Apart from love, all you need is `text[h] = new[text[h] - 'a']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after you've replaced the character you continue searching and may therefore replace the character you just put there. This may happen multiple times. When you find a match, you need to break out of the loop:

```c
void replace_char(string text, string replace, string new){
    int strl = strlen(text);

    for (int h = 0; h < strl; h++){
        for (p = 0; p < 26; p++) {
            if (text[h] == replace[p]) {
                text[h] = new[p];
                break;                   // break out
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An even simpler version would be to just look up the character in the replacement string directly. This works if the characters in `replace` are in a contiguous range (and they are 26 of them as you've hardcoded):

```c
void replace_char(string text, string replace, string new){
    int strl = strlen(text);

    for (int h = 0; h < strl; h++){
        if(text[h] >= replace[0] && text[h] <= replace[25])
            text[h] = new[text[h] - replace[0]];
    }
}
```

---

Or, make sure that `replace` is a contiguous range by taking the first and last character in the range instead:

```c
#include <assert.h>

void replace_char(string text, char first, char last, string new) {
    int strl = strlen(text);

    assert(strlen(new) >= last - first);

    for (int h = 0; h < strl; h++) {
        if (text[h] >= first && text[h] <= last)
            text[h] = new[text[h] - first];
    }
}
```

and call it like so:

```c
replace_char(message, 'a', 'z', Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ted Lyngmo provided the right answer: "need to break out of the inner `for()` loop"

Below is an annotated revision of your code (for your study.)

```
// list header files from "C general" to "program specific"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

// a function defined is a function declared.
// no need to prototype if function definition is ahead of its use in main()
void replace_char( string text, string replace, string newvals ) {
    int h;
    for( h = 0; text[ h ]; h++ ) { // no need to measure. bump into the end

        int p; // declare variables when they are needed

        for( p = 0; replace[ p ]; p++ ) { // 'replace' may not be exactly 26 chars

            if( text[ h ] == replace[ p ] ) {

                // this is called "print debugging"... it is useful sometimes
                printf( "char #%d replacing %c with %c\n", h, text[ h ], newvals[ p ] );

                text[ h ] = newvals[ p ];
                // break; // break out of inner loop and move on to next msg character
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string message = get_string("Type message: ");
    string Alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string Key  =  "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

    replace_char( message, Alpha, Key );

    puts( message ); // alternative function to print str with LF too...

    return 0;
}
```

Commenting out the break statement that should have been present, that print statement shows what was happening:

```
Type message: hello there
char #0 replacing h with i
char #0 replacing i with o
char #0 replacing o with g
char #1 replacing e with t
char #1 replacing t with z
char #1 replacing z with m
char #2 replacing l with s
char #2 replacing s with l
char #3 replacing l with s
char #3 replacing s with l
char #4 replacing o with g
char #6 replacing t with z
char #6 replacing z with m
char #7 replacing h with i
char #7 replacing i with o
char #7 replacing o with g
char #8 replacing e with t
char #8 replacing t with z
char #8 replacing z with m
char #9 replacing r with k
char #10 replacing e with t
char #10 replacing t with z
char #10 replacing z with m
gmllg mgmkm
```

You can add (temporarily) as many print statements as you need so that the program reports what it is doing. It's a good way to find bugs before you start to learn about `debuggers`.

Comment: The print debugging part of your answer was very useful in helping me understand what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner for loop

```
for (h = 0; h < strl; h++){
    for (p = 0; p < 26; p++)
    if (text[h] == replace[p])
    text[h] = new[p];}
```

For example if `text[h]` is equal to `replace[p]` then the character `text[h]` is changed and the inner loop continues its iterations with the new value of `text[h]` And the new value of `text[h]` can be again found in the string `replace`.

At least you need to insert a break statement

```
for (h = 0; h < strl; h++){
    for (p = 0; p < 26; p++)
    { 
        if (text[h] == replace[p])
        {
            text[h] = new[p];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You could use the standard function `strchr` instead of writing manually the inner for loop. For example

```
string replace_char( string text, string replace, string new )
{
    for ( string p = text; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        char *target = strchr( replace, *p );
        if ( target != NULL ) *p = new[target - replace];
    }

    return text;
}
```

Pay attention to that you need to guarantee that lengths of the strings `replace` and `new` are equal each other. Otherwise the function will look more complicated.

Comment: Because of the myriad CV50 questions on SO, you should know that the OP has not yet seen pointers, let alone `char *`... And `[target - replace]` may drive him/her away from the course completely... Just saying...

Comment: @Fe2O3 string is a pointer type. It will be very useful for him if he will know that.

Comment: Useful? or incomprehensible on day 3 of the course?... Your answer; your call...

Comment: @Fe2O3 All new knowledge in programming are useful.

Comment: Code golf (not in an answer). `void replace_char(string p, string n) {
 for( int v,l=strlen(n); *p; p++ )
 v = *p-'a', *p = v<l?n[v]:*p;
}` This comfortably deals with strlen("Key") < 26... Fewer parameters, and 'n' means "Key"... One man's "complicated" is another man's "conditional operator"... Cheers...